# How to specify the Execution Order of Custom Validation Attributes in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have multiple custom validation attributes in property level as well as Class level. I just would would like to know how to set the execution order of ValidationAttributes. Because one of my validation attribute to check "Required Fields" never gets called?

```
public class PhoneNumberFormatAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
 .......
 return new ValidationResult("Invalid Phone Number);
 .......
}
```

---

```
public class RequiredFieldsAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
.........
return new ValidationResult("Field Required");
..........
}
```

---

```
[RequiredFields]
public class MessageRequest
{
   [PhoneNumberFormat]
   public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
}
```

If I get model state error from PhoneNumberFormatAttribute, the RequiredFieldAttribute never gets called.

Comment: Please include some code in your question.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539496/how-can-i-specify-the-order-of-dataannotation-validationattributes?

Comment: If I need to create a  ModelValidatorProvider, will u please help me how to do this?