# MVC 4 Remote Validation Attribute and jQuery .valid(); when is remote validation called?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I have a couple of validations on an property in my view model.

```
[Required(...)]
[Remote(...)]
[RegularExpression(...)]
public string MyProperty { get; set; }
```

I also have jQuery validation frontend, which automatically runs e.g. the regex when I call jQuery's validate's `.valid()`.

My question is: it seems the remote validation attribute is only triggered once the regex is satisfied, e.g. the regex runs front end, is satisfies, and then fires an http request to the remote validation. Is this right? That would be perfect for my need, but I'm not really sure about it.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure but according to the selected answer here:

[How can I specify the order of DataAnnotation ValidationAttribute's?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539496/how-can-i-specify-the-order-of-dataannotation-validationattributes)

They are not necessarily ordered in the way they are placed on the property.

I assume that the remote one will always be the last thing that is done as it needs to go off somewhere to check, whereas the other ones can be done instantly.

So I am not sure if its just pot luck that its running last or if my assumption is correct.

Hope this helps