# MVC Data Annotation And Custom Validation Attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I have a field in a model on which builtin data annotation and custom validation attribute not seems to be working correctly. Looks like there is an issue with the order of there execution.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "UserName")]        
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\s\,]*$", ErrorMessage = "Username Cannot must not contain any spaces or commas")]
[UnqiueUserName]
public string UserName { get; set; }


public class UnqiueUserName : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null && Membership.GetUser(value.ToString()) != null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult
                    (string.Format("UserName Already Exist"));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

If I enter username **user,123** The custom validation attribute executing first and that make the exception to occur.

```
The parameter "username" must not contain a comma
```

But If I enter **user 123** the builtin Data Annotation Regular Expression execute first this time.

I want my Custom Validation attribute after the builtin one. Please suggest

Comment: Try [How can I specify the order of DataAnnotation ValidationAttribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539496/how-can-i-specify-the-order-of-dataannotation-validationattributes)

Comment: @tchelidze answer is correct. However I would suggest to combine RegularExpression and Unique attributes into Unique.